# Применение hover к нумерованному списку

Tags: html, css, hover

Подскажите как подсветить всю строку вместе с порядковым номером?

```css
.wrapper {
  width:650px;
  color:#280505;
  background:#FFFDD0;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin:15px auto;
}
            
.wrapper li {
  padding-left:0px;
}

.wrapper li:hover {
  width:100%;
  height:1.45em;
  background: #280505;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class ="wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li>Вступление</li>
    <li>Проверка домашнего задания</li>
    <li>Тема урока - Любовь. Толкование и объяснение</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вместо подсветки `<li>`, можно делать подсветку псевдо элемента.

```css
.wrapper {
  width:650px;
  color:#280505;
  background:#FFFDD0;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin:15px auto;
}
            
.wrapper li {
  padding-left:0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper li:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.wrapper li:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.1em;
  background: rgb(40, 5, 5);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class ="wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li>Вступление</li>
    <li>Проверка домашнего задания</li>
    <li>Тема урока - Любовь. Толкование и объяснение</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```